# Rcpp - Using the optim function

Tags: c++, r

How to use the varargs functions of the R language, as is the case of the optim function?

Consider the code below where I want to maximize the log-likelihood function `verossimilhanca`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RInside.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double verossimilhanca(Function pdf, NumericVector par, NumericVector x){
  NumericVector log_result = log(pdf(par,x));
  double soma =0;
  for(int i = 0; i < log_result.size(); i++){
    soma += log_result[i];
  }

  return -1*soma;
} 
// [[Rcpp::export]]
List bootC(NumericVector x, NumericVector init_val){ 
  Rcpp::Environment stats("package:stats"); 
  Rcpp::Function optim = stats["optim"];    

  R["my_objective_fn"] = Rcpp::InternalFunction(&verossimilhanca);

  Rcpp::List opt_results = optim(Rcpp::_["par"]  = init_val,
                                 Rcpp::_["fn"]     = Rcpp::InternalFunction(&verossimilhanca),
                                 Rcpp::_["method"] = "BFGS", x);

  return opt_results;
  // x is a data vetor.
}
```

In summary, I have a log-likelihood function and I want to maximize this function and `x` is my data set. I know that `RInside` allows me to create instances of R in C++ but I want to solve this problem only by using the `Rcpp.h` library without resorting to `RInside.h`.

Comment: In short, bad idea. You will get _optmization mostly at the same speed as from R_ with more as you call it from C++.  If you want C++ access, look at (the development version of) nloptr (which you can access from C).

Comment: Also, for standard Rcpp use from R you never want `RInside.h`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. She will be very helpful.

But just to kill my curiosity about a question I have: I know it's possible to make use of an R function and call this function for C ++ code using Rcpp. If this function of R accepts argvar (variable arguments) (...), is there any way to import this function into C ++ via Rcpp and this function prezervar this characteristic, ie is it possible to make use of a  (variable arguments) (...) of the imported function in C++?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `x` with `Rcpp::_["x"] = x` in the arguments of optim function.
It bothers me too until I find [the answer of @coatless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348079/applying-the-optim-function-in-r-in-c-with-rcpp).