# How calling stats::optim from Rcpp causes memory leak?

Tags: rcpp

in part of my code I need to optimize a function from Rcpp (I followed the 2nd answer here [Applying the optim function in R in C++ with Rcpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48348079/applying-the-optim-function-in-r-in-c-with-rcpp)). However, I found that the function leaks memory (very little, but it compounds if it's a part of repeatedly running simulation). I created a minimal reproducible example, but I have no idea where does the leak originate/how to deal with it. Could I ask for guidance on dealing with this issue?

Rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
double objective_function(double x){
  double obj = .666 - x;
  return pow(obj, 2);
}
// [[Rcpp::export(leak)]]
double leak(double a, double b){
 

  // Extract R's optim function
  Rcpp::Environment stats("package:stats");
  Rcpp::Function optim = stats["optim"];
 
  // Call the optim function from R in C++
  Rcpp::List opt_results = optim(Rcpp::_["par"]    = .5,
                                 Rcpp::_["fn"]     = Rcpp::InternalFunction(&objective_function),
                                 Rcpp::_["method"] = "Brent",
                                 Rcpp::_["lower"]  = a,
                                 Rcpp::_["upper"]  = b);
 
  // Extract out the estimated parameter values
  double mu = opt_results[0];
 
  // Return estimated values
  return mu;
}
```

R code:

```
repeat{
  leak(0, 1)
}
```

When I look at my task manager, the RAM usage under Rstudio R Session is steadily increasing (which doesn't happen if I use any other function that just returns a value).

Comment: Does the leak also happen if you call `optim` directly in R, like normal?

Comment: That is a good question @HongOoi . I just tried optimizing the Rcpp defined function from R directly and the leak does not occur. It happens iff I optimize it from within the Rcpp leak function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using macOS + the Instruments leak detector, it seems like `Rcpp::InternalFunction` is leaking:

[image: Instruments leak detector]

And this points us at the code here:

https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/97222bb753c4cd76a4cef7d33c2bfc2e305d1158/inst/include/Rcpp/generated/InternalFunction__ctors.h#L35-L38

Note that we're allocating an object with `new`, but we're also telling `XPtr` *not* to register a delete finalizer:

https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/97222bb753c4cd76a4cef7d33c2bfc2e305d1158/inst/include/Rcpp/XPtr.h#L88-L106

It's not immediately clear to me *why* we do this, but I think it explain the behavior. It could be worth [filing an issue](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues).

Comment: ok, thanks! submitted an issue: https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/1114

Comment: So, there was a leak in the InternalFunction that has been already fixed thanks to the awesome Rcpp team:
https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/commit/a78885679cbcd4ebca63c24b1d04fa928c373b72